# Logstash timezone configuration

Tags: logging, configuration, timezone, logstash

I'm using logstash quite a while, but now I have the problem with timezones.
Logstash is reading a logfile which has the time in UTC. So in summersaving I'm UTC+2.

If I configure Kibana to use UTC, it shows the log files to hours before the current time.

```
Example timezone = "user"
Log.txt 2013-06-22 08:29:10 TestLog
Kibana 2013-06-22 08:29:10 TestLog
Current Time: 10:29

Example timezone = "UTC"
Log.txt 2013-06-22 08:29:10 TestLog
Kibana 2013-06-22 06:29:10 TestLog
Current time: 08:29
```

Because of this issue I can't use the stream.

Thanks for your answer

Comment: If you ever come back to stackoverflow: Could you mark my answer as accepted?

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust the timezone and date of the incoming event with the 'date' filter.  This is two different things.

"Adjust the date" means the filter is capable of changing the event's timestamp to some value derived from the @message, overwriting the default value of when it arrived.  Useful for replaying logs.

"Adjust the timezone" shifts the time according to the delta between system tz and the value set in *this* data filter.

You state you are in UTC+2, and the event comes from UTC.  Assuming a tag of "mytag":

```
filters {
  date {
    tags => ["mytag"]
    timezone => "utc"
    add_tag => ["tz_utc"]
  }
}
```

I added a tag to make it easier to filter for it in kibana, etc.